# Remove previous marker (Google Maps)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, marker

I am using Shreerang Patwardhan's code for Javascript geocoding. However, I am having difficulities regarding the removal of the previous marker when entering a new address. I have Googled and experimented but I just can't get the result I want. I want the previous marker removed/hidden when a new marker gets placed.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Maps API v3 Example : Geocoding Simple</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div align="center" style="height: 30px; width: 430px">
      <input id="address" type="textbox">
      <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">
    </div>
    <div id="map" style="height:200px; width: 430px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize()
{
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.7964,79.5410),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
}

function codeAddress()
{
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status)
    {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

The code that I'm using is the same code as in [this JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shreerang/F4Sd2/):

Comment: you need to do an marker.setMap(null); marker is teh reference to previous marker

Comment: Where should I place that? I have no markers at all.

Comment: uh, you do.  Place @VinodLouis's line immediately before where you do `var marker = new google.maps.Marker`

Comment: @duncan but for that a safe check is needed else for 1st time it will throw error till marker is defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do an `marker.setMap(null);` marker is the reference to previous marker

```
 if(marker)
     marker.setMap(null)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/F4Sd2/637/ is the working fiddle